# Replicate segmented cell style of macOS Big Sur

Tags: swift, menubar, macos-big-sur, nssegmentedcontrol

I am trying to replicate the style of the Finder. I have a `NSSegmentedControl` that is hosted in the menu bar, however, the style is a little bit different.

This is how the finder looks like:

[image: Finder]

And this is how my `NSSegmentedControl` looks like:

[image: My App]

The width of the items seems to be a little bit bigger. There is also a small gap in between the items.

How can I replicate the Finder style?

Comment: Which style are you using?  And which style do you think they are using?

Comment: I simply dragged a NSSegmentedControl onto the NSToolBar. I did not change any properties, so it is the default style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there were two problems:

- Do not use a fixed width for your cells.
- Select the `Rounded` style.